# Best Billing Date selection for multiple Credit card utilization

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I have 2 credit cards. This card has a billing date of 20th of a month and payment date of 7/8th of month.

1. What is the ideal billing date for the second credit card?
2. Should I keep the billing dates similar or space apart?

Considering:

1. Salary is credited within first 5 days of month.
2. Grace Period for both cards are 18 days.

Comment: Just a quick observation that you don't _have_ to wait to be billed, now that balance can be checked and paid online.

Comment: @keshlam this is exactly right.  OP, pay when **YOU** want to pay the bill. (Note that this requires getting ahead one month with the minimum payment. After that. you’ll always be ahead of the bank.)

Comment: More important than picking a due date is knowing where *all* of your money goes, and when it goes there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your salary is paid to you once a month early in the month, it would seem to make sense to pay all your big bills soon after payday. Doing so allows you to know how much money you have left to get to the next payday.

If you get paid twice a month, some people like to put some big bills early in the month, and the rest after the 2nd paycheck of the month. Of course if you get paid every two weeks it is hard to lineup paychecks with bills.

Picking the due date can be critical if you are treading water financially, but if you have significantly more income than expenses, then you may find that it doesn't make a difference financially.